# custom control to be used in multiple apps that are in different VS solutions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, custom-controls, winjs

I need to create some custom control that will need to be used in multiple Store Apps. Can a WinJS custom control be used across multiple Visual Studio solutions or is it limited to be used in one solution only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes custom control is possible in winjS only you need to add the js file where you create a custom control to include in the project.

and after placing js file inside ur html in the script tag You need to use the processall function to get access to the namespaces  created.

Here's a full description fromt he link go through both of them .

The code project one seems easy for testing . downlaod and see . integrate it's js in your project and follow the steps

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/469657/How-to-Write-a-WinJS-Custom-Control)
[MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/11/building-a-custom-control-using-the-windows-library-for-javascript-winjs.aspx)

the msdn will guide you through how to add and cal them. :) Give a look and let me know if it works or have any doubt.